# get previous values from older record in same table

Tags: postgresql

I am having activity table in following form

```
    id    parent_id    values       created_on   modified_on  etc..

     2       39         Hockey
     3       39         Solo
     2       39         Cricket
     3       39         Classic
     2       39         Football
     3       39         Salsa
```

Now i want to add `2 Column` in `Select query` like

```
 id    parent_id   values              Previous Value     new Value  created_on   modified_on  etc..

 2       39         Hockey             Cricket            Hockey
 3       39         Solo               Classic            Solo
 2       39         Cricket            Football           Cricket
 3       39         Classic            Salsa              Classic
 2       39         Football                              Football
 3       39         Salsa                                 Salsa
```

As last records are the `Oldest ever records` so does not have any `Previous value` similarly `Newest records` have same values in both column `new value and value`.

Comment: There is no primary key in your table.

Comment: In your example table, please show the column in the `activity` table that holds the value that you use to determine what order the events happened.

Comment: @MikeOrganek it is sorted based on time `desc` , now i have to add `Previous value` for e.g `Cricket` for id `2` and so on

Comment: What is the difference between the columns `values` and `new Value`?

Comment: @forpas Both are exactly same at any point of time both should be the same.

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you use. Is it Mysql or Postgresql?

Comment: So there is also a column like time in the table?

Comment: @forpas it is already sorted on `modified_on desc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `LAG()` window function:

```
select "id", "parent_id", "values",
  lag("values") over (partition by "id", "parent_id" order by "modified_on") "Previous Value",
  "values" "new Value"             
from tablename 
order by "modified_on" desc
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wEcjKoPX6zERycncvkurQb/1).
Results:

```
| id  | parent_id | values   | Previous Value | new Value |
| --- | --------- | -------- | -------------- | --------- |
| 2   | 39        | Hockey   | Cricket        | Hockey    |
| 3   | 39        | Solo     | Classic        | Solo      |
| 2   | 39        | Cricket  | Football       | Cricket   |
| 3   | 39        | Classic  | Salsa          | Classic   |
| 2   | 39        | Football |                | Football  |
| 3   | 39        | Salsa    |                | Salsa     |
```